# Hiding a row if text box is hidden

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that lists parts required for a job, and then within each part it has rows that show locations and quantities of parts on-hand.  The main list has a header (part number, description, quantity) which is only shown once at the top because it is not within the grouping.  However, the second header (on-hand quantity, location) is within the grouping so it repeats.  I would like it to only show once.

I have tried using the hide duplicates property for the header text boxes, but this still leaves blank rows.  I have also tried setting the row visibility using a comparison between ReportItem!lblOnHand.Value and Previous(ReportItem!lblOnHand.Value) but this gives me an aggregate error.

This is what the report is displaying now:

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the row visibility rather than the individual text boxes. Right-click the row header to access the setting..

[image]

You should (untested) be able to use the same logic as you have now. If this does not work then you will need to test if the group is the first group and use that in the expression, something like...

```
=Fields!Partnumber.Value <> FIRST(Fields!Partnumber.Value, "myGroupOrDatasetNameHere")
```

The above would hide thew row if the part number in the current context is not the same as the first part number in the group or dataset name specified.

Comment: I'm not trying to hide the detail rows, I'm trying to hide the header row.  I thought I could use your method with ReportItem, but that didn't work.

Comment: The header must be in a row though, so select the header row, right click and choose 'row visibility'

Comment: I can get to row visibility, the question I am asking is what logic can I use in there since the detail rows could be different...I want to compare previous header row information to the current, if they are the same then hide it; only showing the first header row (since it will duplicate for every detail row).